# Swift get Facebook AccessToken

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I'm trying to obtain the Facebook Accesstoken.  when I print accessToken it returns a object with appId and authenticationToken,  How do I parse out the token?
 I am using the following code:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):

            print("accessToken: " + String(describing: accessToken))
            break

        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42266558/5461400 try this

Comment: you can directly get the access token `FBSDKAccessToken.current()`

Answer (score 7):

The token you're trying to parse is a struct

the **actual** token is:

```
accessToken.authenticationToken
```

your code should be like that:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
    switch loginResult {
    case .failed(let error):
        print(error)
    case .cancelled:
        print("User cancelled login.")
    case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):

        print("accessToken: " +  accessToken.authenticationToken)
        break

    }
}
```